# I thought await continued on the same thread as the caller, but it seems not to

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I thought one of the points about async/await is that when the task completes, the continuation is run on the same context when the await was called, which would, in my case, be the UI thread.

So for example:

```
Debug.WriteLine("2: Thread ID: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
await fs.ReadAsync(data, 0, (int)fs.Length);
Debug.WriteLine("3: Thread ID: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
```

I would NOT expect this:

```
2: Thread ID: 10
3: Thread ID: 11
```

What gives?  Why is the thread ID for the continuation different than the UI thread?

According to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)[^] I would need to explicitly call ConfigureAwait to change the behavior of the continuation context!

Comment: Can you write a minimal repro and post here or in a Gist?

Comment: Are you using `ConfigureAwait(false)` anywhere *before* this fragment?   Or perhaps this code fragment is used inside an async lambda like this: `await Task.Run(async () => { /* no synchronization context here! */ })` ?

Comment: Nope.  Didn't even know about ConfigureAwait until I started googling this issue.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

When you `await`, by default the `await` operator will capture the current "context" and use that to resume the `async` method.

This "context" is `SynchronizationContext.Current` unless it is `null`, in which case it is `TaskScheduler.Current`. (If there is no currently-running task, then `TaskScheduler.Current` is the same as `TaskScheduler.Default`, the thread pool task scheduler).

It's important to note that a `SynchronizationContext` or `TaskScheduler` does not necessarily imply a particular *thread*. A UI `SynchronizationContext` will schedule work to the UI thread; but the ASP.NET `SynchronizationContext` will not schedule work to a particular thread.

I suspect that the cause of your problem is that you are invoking the `async` code too early. When an application starts, it just has a plain old regular thread. That thread only becomes the UI thread when it does something like `Application.Run`.

Comment: Wow - that's exactly it -- Normally this function gets called when the user clicks on a folder and the UI is up and running, but I'm also calling this function right before Application.Run to initialize with the root directory!  I would not have thought of that -- thank you so much!

Comment: hello.  Https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html   it says there that asp.net does by default also returns on the calling thread. it is a particular thread. it just differs from request to request. Why does asp.net do that by default ? does it have any thing to do with the relation to the reuqestcontext?

Comment: @eranotzap: That blog post states that ASP.NET (classic) resumes on a request context (not a particular thread). The request context manages things like `HttpContext.Current` and the current culture. ASP.NET Core has a better design that does not require a `SynchronizationContext`: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html

Comment: @StephenCleary My question is regarding ASP.net mvc. the await would return on the calling thread if ConfigureAwait(false) is not used, correct ?

Comment: @eranotzap: It might or might not. It *will* resume on a thread that has the same `HttpContext.Current`, culture, etc. This thread might or might not be the same thread that was running the code before the `await`.

Comment: @StephenCleary that's a great answer, Thanks. I didn't understand that from the blog post. And it's a blog post i send colleges to remind them to use ConfigureAwait(false)

Answer (score 6):

The `await` expression will use the value of `SynchronizationContext.Current` to return control flow back to the thread on which it occurred.  In cases where this is `null` it will default to the `TaskScheduler.Current`.  The implementation relies solely on this value to change the thread context when the `Task` value completes.  It sounds like in this case the `await` is capturing a context that isn't bound to the UI thread

Comment: Actually, if `SynchronizationContext.Current` is `null`, then `await` will use `TaskScheduler.Current`. And neither of those schedulers necessarily return back to the *same* thread. But I agree that the op is likely not calling this *from* the UI thread.

Comment: I am a little late for the party, but how can i *enforce* resuming on the same thread? After a call to `Task.Delay` my function always resumes on a different thread, which i must prevent.

Answer (score -1):

By default, Windows Forms sets up the synchronization context when the first control is created.

So you can do like this:

```cs
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    var f = new Form1();
    //var s=SynchronizationContext.Current;
    //var s2=TaskScheduler.Current;
    GetAsync();
    Application.Run(f);
}

static async Task<bool> GetAsync()
{
    MessageBox.Show($"thread id {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
    bool flag = await Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() =>
    {
       Thread.Sleep(1000);
       return true;
    });
    MessageBox.Show($"thread id {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
    return flag;
}
```

Comment: The `Task.Factory.StartNew`+`Thread.Sleep` is a bad example IMHO. It should be better to just `await Task.Delay(1000);`.