# Best way to call functions asynchronously

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, async-await

I trying get a string to set three label text asynchronously, Firstly I tried with this

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = await SetTextbox(3);
    label2.Text = await SetTextbox(2);
    label3.Text = await SetTextbox(1);
}

private async Task<string> SetTextbox(int delaySeconds)
{
    Thread.Sleep(delaySeconds * 1000);
    return "Done.";
}
```

As you can see I try to add some delay in every call to know what label text should be set first, but this code doesn't work, the GUI still freezing and the processes still being synchronous.

For now I make it work using Task.Run:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var proc1 = Task.Run(async () => { label1.Text = await SetTextbox(3); });
     var proc2 = Task.Run(async () => { label2.Text = await SetTextbox(2); });
     var proc3 = Task.Run(async () => { label3.Text = await SetTextbox(1); });

     await Task.WhenAll(proc1, proc2, proc3);
}
```

but something tells me that this is not right way to achieve this, Can you tell me what would be the best way to do this or this is good solution?

Comment: I would also advice the use of `await Task.Delay(delaySeconds * 1000)` instead of the `Thread.Sleep`. The first one is made for use with `async` the latter is for when you're using threads.

Comment: What if you just change `Thread.Sleep(delaySeconds * 1000);` to `await Task.Delay(delaySeconds * 1000);`

Comment: Thread.Sleep()  can be (and should be) used to simulate _synchronous_ work. Task.Delay() would be wrong in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SetTextbox` method is not a well behaved asynchronous method. The expected behavior of an asynchronous method is to return a `Task` immediately. Blocking the caller with `Thread.Sleep` breaks this expectation.

Now if we are handed with a badly behaving asynchronous method, `Task.Run` is our friend. Important: the only thing that should be wrapped inside the `Task.Run` is the blocking asynchronous method. Any UI related code should stay outside:

```
private async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var task1 = Task.Run(async () => await BadBlockingMethodAsync(1));
     var task2 = Task.Run(async () => await BadBlockingMethodAsync(2));
     var task3 = Task.Run(async () => await BadBlockingMethodAsync(3));

     await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3);

     label1.Text = await task1;
     label2.Text = await task2;
     label3.Text = await task3;
}
```

As a side note, `SetTextbox` is an improper name for an asynchronous method. According to the [guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap#naming-parameters-and-return-types) the method should have an `Async` suffix (`SetTextboxAsync`).

Comment: SetTextbox  is not async at all. Async (behaviour) does not come from the `async` keyword but from `await`ing something that _is_ async.

Comment: @Henk Holterman according to the official docs, asynchronous is a method that returns an awaitable type. The `SetTextbox` returns `Task<string>`, which is awaitable, so the method is asynchronous. *"Asynchronous methods in TAP include the Async suffix after the operation name for methods that return awaitable types, such as Task, Task<TResult>, ValueTask, and ValueTask<TResult>."* ([citation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap#naming-parameters-and-return-types)).

Comment: It is awaitable, yes. But it is not really async. It is faking it, as per the compiler warning. And in the first sample everything runs on the main thread, synchronously and sequentially.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I agree that the method fakes to be asynchronous based on its implementation, but having a name that ignores the official naming recommendations doesn't make things any better.

Comment: Still, the better solution would be to keep the name and change the signature. You can still run a `void M() {}`  with Task.Run() and it would be more honest. And avoid some useless async/await overhead at the same time.

Comment: @HenkHolterman the `SetTextbox` method is currently so obscure regarding its intentions, that I wouldn't dare suggesting architectural improvements. 

Comment: Yes, when posting my answer I realized it should be called `GenerateString[Async](int)`, it is not setting a TextBox at all. And it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Setting those 3 labels are not dependent operations right. In that case, you can run all the method parallel and get their result once all done like

```
private async Task button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var t1 = SetTextbox(3);
     var t2 = SetTextbox(2);
     var t3 = SetTextbox(1);

     string[] data = await Task.WhenAll(new[] { t1, t2, t3 });

    label1.Text = data[0];
    label2.Text = data[1];
    label3.Text = data[2];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous does not mean that it will execute in parallel - which is what you need if you want UI to stop freezing. And that is why Task.Run works.
Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32726294/is-async-await-using-task-run-starting-a-new-thread-asynchronously)
Your Task.Run solution should be ok - it is one of C# intended ways of running something in parallel