# Why sync context is not working for await?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21839382/2631076) says

> by default the await operator will capture the current "context" and use that to resume the async method.

I am trying this code in my console app:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Test().Wait();
}

private static async Task Test()
{
    var context = new SynchronizationContext();
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(context);
    Console.WriteLine("Thread before: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    Console.WriteLine(await GetResultAsync());
    Console.WriteLine("Thread after: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
}

private static async Task<string> GetResultAsync()
{
    return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thread inside: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        return "Hello stackoverflow!";
    });
}
```

... and get this out:

```
Thread before: 1
Thread inside: 3
Hello stackoverflow!
Thread after: 3
```

Why? And also how I should set sync context if I want to use the same thread after await?

Comment: They use the term context here explicitly because not all contexts are bound to a single thread. In a console application, there are no built-in reasons to favour one thread ahead of others (unlike UI frameworks with a UI thread).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why?

`new SynchronizationContext()` [by convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx) is the same as a `null` `SynchronizationContext`. Both "no SyncCtx" and "default SyncCtx" just queue work to the thread pool.

There is not a 1:1 relationship between `SynchronizationContext` and a specific thread. For example:

- The WinForms UI `SynchronizationContext` will queue work to the single UI thread. AFAIK, the WinForms `SynchronizationContext` is a singleton, so there is a 1:1 mapping *in this case*.
- The WPF `SynchronizationContext` will queue work to its `Dispatcher`. Last time I checked, WPF will create a new *instance* for each top-level window, even if they all use the same thread. So there is a N:1 mapping.
- The thread pool (default/`null`) `SynchronizationContext` can queue work to any thread pool thread. If you don't create a default `SynchronizationContext` instance, there is a 1:N mapping.

> And also how I should set sync context if I want to use the same thread after await?

You'll need to use a custom `SynchronizationContext`. I recommend using my [`AsyncContext` or `AsyncContextThread` types](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx), since that's not straightforward code to write.

Comment: Actually, in WPF `SynchronizationContext.Current` is never the same after `await`, where the task completes asynchronously. That's because `Dispatcher` executes every callback on a unique instance of `DispatcherSynchronizationContext`. Kind of in controversy with `continueOnCapturedContext` argument of `ConfigureAwait`, IMO.

Comment: Weird! That behavior has changed since a few years ago, then.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert on this topic, I just have read some tutorials.

Code after `await` will be run as a task continuation with captured synchronization context. You provided `new SynchronizationContext()` which uses `ThreadPool` to execute that code.

Source code: [link](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/synchronizationcontext.cs,8b34a86241c7b423)

Look at `Send` method in `SynchronizationContext` class:

```
public virtual void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, Object state)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(d), state);
}
```

So as you see, the continuation will not be run on `main` thread. It uses `ThreadPool`.

When `GetResultAsync()` is done, `thread 3` is free to use, and is immediately reused by `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` in `SynchronizationContext`.

So you need to create your own synchronization context for console application.

Didn't read, but maybe this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/01/20/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/) will help.