# Is this function Asynchronous?

Tags: c#

I'm not sure if this code is Asynchronous. I call this function using await from my main controller and within the function I use await on the LINQ query and .ToListAsync() - but after the query I have the foreach loop which may defeat the purpose of async on the query.

Main Controller Call:

```
case "getassets":
    reply = await GetAssets();
    break;
```

Function:

```
public async Task<ReplyObj> GetAssets()
{
    ReplyObj obj = new ReplyObj();
    obj.Result = new List<dynamic>();
    dynamic AssetRecords = await _context.Asset.FromSql("SELECT * FROM Asset").ToListAsync();

    foreach (var objAsset in AssetRecords)
    {
        obj.Result.Add(new Asset() 
        {
            AssetId = objAsset.AssetId,
            Name = objAsset.Name,
            Description = objAsset.Description,
            PriceDecimals = objAsset.PriceDecimals 
        });
    }

    obj.Success = true;
    obj.Message = "";

    return obj;        
}
```

This call will have many requests hitting it, I want to know for sure that its using async correctly. Thank you!

Comment: Why do you think the loop would defeat the purpose?  The DB call is going to take much much longer than that loop and during that time the thread is free to do other stuff.

Comment: Why isn't the `ReplyObj.Result` a dynamic? What about a `ReplyObj<T>`?

Comment: The only async on this is `ToListAsync`. until that will be ran on the current thread. You should run the query using `Task.Run()` in combination with `TaskCompletionSource<TResult>`. Probably the are already FromSqlAsync methods or extensions

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Saying "until that will be ran on the current thread" makes it sound like awaiting ToListAsync will somehow spin up a different thread, which is not correct

Comment: Because I felt like the await should cover the entire function, not just part of it. However that does make sense thank you @juharr - ReplyObj contains a dynamic list "Result".

Comment: @chill94 that's a little nitpicking, but _`which is not correct`_ is bluntly.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Putting something that is primarily IO bound into `Task.Run` is mostly pointless, it's better to use actual async methods for IO and use `Task.Run` for CPU bound (or IO if there are no async methods available).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things that I want to point out:

1. `dynamic AssetRecords = await _context.Asset.FromSql("SELECT * FROM Asset").ToListAsync();` 
    When you are using `_context.Asset` it will return all the Asset rows that you have. Why would you execute another query on the table when the `Asset` it self is giving all that you need? Hence, to me this is redundant thing.
2. And if you use `select` method and then get the list `asyncronously` then you will have eliminated the the foreach loop and it will cost only one `await` call and query processing. See code sample below:

   ```
   public async Task<ReplyObj> GetAssets()
   {
       ReplyObj obj = new ReplyObj();
       return obj.Result = await _context.Asset.Select(s => new
       {
           AssetId = s.AssetId,
           Name = s.Name,
           Description = s.Description,
           PriceDecimals = s.PriceDecimals
       }).ToListAsync();
   }
   ```

This could now be your true async method.

PS:
If you want to show your code to experts for review, I would suggest joining [StackExchange CodeReview Community](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what looks and feels right, the await now covers the entire function. Your right it was redundant thank you for pointing that out, I was really just after the Async functionality.

Comment: Your code gives me: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: int AssetId, string Name, string Description, int PriceDecimals>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<dynamic>'  Is there a way to apply the Asset type to the object I'm creating.. or make these two compatible?

Comment: I fixed it, here's the new code:             obj.Result = await _context.Asset.Select(s => new Asset
            {
                AssetId = s.AssetId,
                Name = s.Name,
                Description = s.Description,
                PriceDecimals = s.PriceDecimals
            }).Cast<dynamic>().ToListAsync();

Answer (score 1):

To begin, here's a couple of references for async/await in C# that I'd suggest reviewing:

- [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)
- [SO Community Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-await)

The simple (high-level) answer is that awaiting your sql call will return control up the call stack and continue execution. In this case, that means it will go up to:

```
reply = await GetAssets();
```

Which will in turn return control to whatever function called that, etc. etc..

With that said, if all of your async calls in your call stack are immediately being awaited, then async won't end up buying you anything/changing the flow of control. To say, keep in mind that [async != threading](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benwilli/2015/09/10/tasks-are-still-not-threads-and-async-is-not-parallel/).

Comment: This is where I was a bit confused, so its like a cycle between calling the function and the await on the Query, well what happens with the foreach loop, does that start blocking the thread?

Comment: Running CPU bound code (ie. processing data in a foreach loop) will not yield control back up the call stack. Does that help? I'd encourage you to keep digging into async/await to make sure you've got a solid grasp of what's going on, as it can definitely be somewhat tricky when you're first getting started. Though I was criticized for pointing it out above, one of the biggest takeaways I can offer is that it awaiting does not create new threads. It creates a state machine on the current thread, giving it a point at which to resume when the IO bound call completes (on the same thread).

Comment: I realized after re-reading my post that the parenthetical note, "(on the same thread)", is an incorrect statement. Here's a link pointing out [my error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21838651/i-thought-await-continued-on-the-same-thread-as-the-caller-but-it-seems-not-to).